# MaxscriptEditor print function can't print on listener

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm using maxscript editor to write a python script.I used print function to check the result before,but one day it can't print anything to listener suddenly,there nothing output in listener,but the same value can be write in a txt file.Could anyone help me make the print function available?This has a great impact on my debugging,thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the Listener in Python mode?

Comment: Sorry for not reply,i found import sys module and set default encoding to utf-8 caused this problem.So I don't set the default encoding anymore.